# android array data store problem

Tags: android

i want to store some element String.XML's array. Values are given bellow

```
<string-array name="values">


    <item>Bupivicaine+Fentanyl</item>
    <item>Bupivicaine>Diamorphine</item>

</string-array>
```

Now how can i store these values in array. because when i use "+" in elements this doesn't display. i have to show it "Bupivicaine+Fentanyl" format... and at the point of ">" it is giving error in string.xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace the '+' character and '>' with HTML Entity Code.
Have a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_ascii.asp) for the respective entity code.

Comment: @Shalini, incase that helped, you should accept Raunak's answer.